# How to render posts by date using a button to scroll day by day

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The app I'm working on it meant to manage food orders. The user log in, creates an order using a simple form, the order is saved to a database,
The home page, by default, takes the current date and displays the orders of the day.

I added some buttons at the end of the page to be able to move to the next day or the previous day, to be able to see past or future orders.
I was able to manage the date handling using two simple functions that takes the day and add +1 or -1 to move to the next/previous day.
GOAL: the goal would be to click those buttons and be able to see tomorrow's orders, yesterday's orders etc.
ISSUE: When I click the buttons the date is displayed correctly but if I move to a day that supposed to have orders, none of those are displayed (the page displays only the date and the message that supposed to be displayed when there are no orders).
I checked the database and the orders are saved correctly and retrieved correctly by the query so, I'm assuming, I'm making a mistake in the way I'm using the routes. I tried to find similar situations but I couldn't find much.

routes:

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    session['date'] = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    today = session.get('date')
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(date=today).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, date=today)


@main.route("/timeline/<string:when>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def timeline(when):
    session_date = session.get('date')
    main_date = datetime.strptime(session_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
    if when == 'next':
        new_date = next_day(main_date)
        session['date'] = new_date
    if when == 'prev':
        new_date = prev_day(main_date)
        session['date'] = new_date

    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(date=new_date).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, date=new_date)
```

home page html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if posts.items %}
      {% for post in posts.items %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + post.author.image_file) }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.author.username) }}">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
              <small><b>{{ post.date }}</b></small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.name }}</a></h2>
            <h5>{{ post.phone_number }}</h5>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.order }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.post_code }}</p>
            <p><small class="text-muted">Order taken on: {{ post.date_posted.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') }}</small></p>
          </div>
        </article>
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <h2>{{ date }} <br> No orders recorded so far.</h2>
      <p>To add a new order, select the voice "New Order" on the navigation bar above.</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% for page_num in posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
      {% if page_num %}
        {% if posts.page == page_num %}
          <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('main.home', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
        {% else %}
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('main.home', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
        {% endif %}
      {% else %}
        ...
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <nav aria-label="Date navigation">
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('main.timeline', when='prev') }}">Prev Day</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('main.timeline', when='next') }}">Next Day</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance to whoever can help, I hope is clear what the issue is.
Cheers.

EDIT 1 - FIRST TRY USING THE APPROACH SUGGESTED BY ANDREW CLARK ANSWER, STILL NOT WORKING:

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@main.route("/home/", defaults={'view_date': date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")})
@main.route("/home/<string:view_date>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home(view_date):
    session['date'] = view_date
    today = session.get('date')
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(date=today).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)

    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, date=today)


@main.route("/redirect_home/<string:when>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def redirect_home(when):
    session_date = session.get('date')
    main_date = datetime.strptime(session_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    if when == 'next':
        new_date = next_day(main_date)
        session['date'] = new_date
    if when == 'prev':
        new_date = prev_day(main_date)
        session['date'] = new_date

    return redirect(url_for('main.home', view_date=new_date))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

BUG:
The problem was in how the date format was handled by the two functions named next_day() and prev_day(): after doing the math to get the next (or the previous) day, the integers are converted back in strings to be able to return a date string.
The problem is that in the query, the table is expecting dates with zeros, like 07-04-2021, but instead the string returned was without zeros (7-4-2021). Because of that the variable posts is empty, therefore nothing would be visualized in the html page.
SOLUTION:
the two functions are being changed as follow:

```
def next_day(date):  # function takes a datetime object
    date = date + timedelta(days=1)
    return date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')


def prev_day(date):  # function takes a datetime object
    date = date - timedelta(days=1)
    return date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Thanks to the user Andrew Clark for the help.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you change the date, also redirect to your desired route w/ the new date as a parameter

```
return redirect(url_for('route_name', date_parameter=XXX))
```

Edit1:
And make sure you use that parameter date inside your route as an input value into your other functions, form population, etc.

<s>Edit 2: replace XXX with your string date</s>

```
return redirect(url_for('timeline', when=XXX))
```

Edit3 (ACTUAL SOLUTION):
Okay you need your home route to have date parameter.
How I have handled this, if you want it to default to current date.
In your base jinja layout, instead of having the home button direct to 'home', have it direct to a new route you create called 'redirect_home'.

```
@main.route("/redirect_home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def redirect_home():
    session['date'] = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    today = session.get('date')
    # now that you have today's date, redirect to home route
    return redirect(url_for('home', view_date=today))
```

Then you need to change your home route so that you're no longer finding today's date. You are just accepting a parameter for the date.

```
@main.route("/home/<view_date>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home(view_date):
    today = view_date
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(date=today).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, date=today)
```

And then whenever you are pressing previous or next, find the new date, make it a string, and send it as a parameter w/ a redirect back to home.
This is the solution. Cheers

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you mean. The new parameters (posts and date) are passed to the render_template() function. If I'm not mistaken the function redirect() doesn't take additional parameters.

Comment: If you want to change something no your current route, you need to redirect back to itself and provide the change as a parameter. For example, if when "@main.route("/timeline/<string:when>" is your date. You need to redirect like I showed you. and send the new date as parameter when

Comment: Oh okay I'm looking at your code a bit deeper now. I see the issue. One second I'll add to my solution.

Comment: did this help you @Py_Rog

Comment: Can you show me the code? Add the question maybe at the end?
Are you converting your new date to a string before sending it?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I edited the question adding what I tried so far. I implemented your suggestion: I had to add a default value to the home route (to pass a value for the first time the route is called). The date is manage and visualize correctly but still the page doesn't shows any posts when a day with posts is selected. The query seems to work correctly though.